# Numeric data type in decimals javascript

Tags: javascript

It might sound stupid while reading this question, but tried various ways to resolve this issue at my end.

I have a variable say **A: number**. I'm performing some calculation on it. The calculation has floating result say **123.453** .

When I use **parseFloat().toFixed(2)** it gives error saying cannot assign string to numeric data type, since toFixed() returns string.

I just want to assign my result in two decimal places to variable **A**.

Comment: `parseFloat('123.345').toFixed(2)`?

Comment: Sounds like you are using a type system like TypeScript or flowjs.

Comment: Why not just `123.453.toFixed(2)`?

Comment: It sounds like you're doing a presentation layer operation here. I'd say move the .toFixed to where you actually need it at and not in the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toFixed` turns a number into a string. If you want to turn a number into a number, use [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round):

```
const fixedNumber = Math.round(123.453 * 100) / 100;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code to solve your problem:

```
let a: number = 123.345;
a = parseFloat(a.toFixed(2)); // Assigning without type errors
console.log(a); // 123.34
console.log(typeof a); // number
```

Comment: Why are you parsing what you already know is a float as a float?

Comment: toFixed() returns a string. The question is trimming and assigning a variable of number type (typescript, I guess so)